# Citing multiple parts of one website APA

Tags: citations, citation-style, website

I'm writing a small research paper (University of Applied Sciences, Bachelor level) where I cite and reference some information from a company's website.

I currently have the specific pages of the website from which I pull the different citations/references individually mentionned in my bibliography like so:

> Company Name (sd). *page name*. Consulted on September 05, 2019, from the website of Company Name: https://www.company_name.com/specific_page
>
> Company Name (sd). _ different page name_. Consulted on September 05, 2019, from the website of Company Name: https://www.company_name.com/anoter_specific_page

However, in the text of the paper, whenever I cite or reference the information of the website, if I follow the APA style I'll have something like:

> A direct quote of the company (Company Name)

Which, as far as I can tell is the correct way to reference the bibliography. However, within the text, all different pages I reference get the same in-line attribution, specifically:

> relevant quote (Company Name)

Is there a better/different way of handling this while adhering to the APA style guide? 
For example, should I just add the website as a whole to the bibliography and specify the specific page in-line like so:

> Bibliography
>
> Company Name (sd). Consulted on September 05, 2019, from the website of Company Name: https://www.company_name.com/

and then in the text itself:

> A direct quote of the company (Company Name, website_page_name)

Comment: The APA Style blog is very helpful in these matters. https://blog.apastyle.org/apastyle/2016/11/writing-website-in-text-citations-and-references.html

Comment: Per the blog, you can append the year with a letter, i.e. (Foo, 2019a) and (Foo, 2019b).

Comment: @Compass do I add the letter to the bibliography as well?

Comment: @FMashiro yes, otherwise it wouldn't correlate with anything.